# Why YUI.lang.extend implements Inheritance this way?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, oop, yui

I'm reading YUI2.8.1 source code yahoo/yahoo.js.

The YAHOO.lang.extend method is implemented this way http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/build/yahoo/yahoo.js

I don't understand why it creates another F function. IMHO, below code should also work(ignoring overrides part)

```
function extend (subc, superc ) {
    if (!superc||!subc) {
          throw new Error("extend failed, please check that " +
                    "all dependencies are included.");
    }
    subc.prototype=new superc();
    subc.prototype.constructor=subc;
    subc.superclass=superc.prototype;
}
```

There must be reason that YUI implements it this way, but I cannot figure it out.
Anybody can shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to JavaScript so correct me if I'm wrong, but in your example, it seems that you are making an assumption about the superclass' constructor (that they will never accept any arguments).

[This page](http://www.3site.eu/doc/#intermediate) goes into depth on inheritance with an intermediate constructor which might answer your queries.